# React.js: Adding an item to the Cart doesn't update UI immediately

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I build an e-commerce MERN app which has a **Add to Cart** feature.

But for some reason, adding an item to the **Cart** doesn't update the UI immediately. 
Even reloading the page doesn't work. Then I log out and sign in again, and, boom, I can see the `added item` in the **user cart**.

I have tested server side, it works fine, updates immediately.

One more important note:I have an **admin feature** and as an admin I fetch and can see all registered users including their carts. So, in there the users' cart is updating automatically in contrast with the current user component.
I am wondering what I am doing wrong here.
 Any help will be much appreciated.

Redux: Product Actions

```
export const checkoutProduct = (product: Product): ProductActions => {
  return {
    type: BUY_PRODUCT,
    payload: {
      product,
    },
  }
}



export const checkout = (productId: string, userId: string) => {
  return (dispatch: Dispatch, getState: any) => {
    dispatch(fetchProductRequest())
    axios
      .patch(
        `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/user/inCart/${userId}`,
        { id: productId },
        tokenConfig(getState)
      )
      .then((response) => {
        const product = response.data
        dispatch(checkoutProduct(product))
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        dispatch(fetchProductFailure(error.message))
      })
  }
}
```

Product Reducer:

```
    case BUY_PRODUCT: {
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                product: action.payload,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                isPurchased: true,
                error: '',
            }
        }
```

User Dashboard containing cart

```
function Profile({ isTabletOrMobile }: isTabletOrMobileProps) {
    const user = useSelector((state: AppState) => state.user.currentUser)
    const isAuthenticated = useSelector(
        (state: AppState) => state.user.isAuthenticated
    )
    
    return (
        <>
            <Card
                href="#card-example-link-card"
                header={user?.firstName}
                meta={user?.cart ? 'Your purchase' : null}
                description={
                    !user?.cart || user?.cart[0] === null ? (
                        <div>cart is empty</div>
                    ) : user?.isAdmin ? null : (
                        user.cart &&
                        user.cart.map((shoes: Product) => (
                            <ul>
                                <li>Name: {shoes.name}</li>
                                <li>Price: {shoes.price}</li>
                            </ul>
                        ))
                    )
                }
                extra={<div> email: {user?.email}</div>}
            ></Card>
        </>
    )
}

export default Profile
```

AddToCart component, only relevant code:

```
import { removeProduct, checkout } from '../../redux'

function CartItem({ cart }: CartItemProps) {

    const handleBuyProd = () => {
        dispatch(checkout(cart._id, user.id))
        setTimeout(() => {
            history.push('/')
        }, 3000)
    }

    return (
        <>
          <Card>
            {isAuthenticated && (
              <Button color="green" onClick={handleBuyProd}>
                Checkout
              </Button>
            )}      
          </Card>
       </>
    )
}

export default CartItem
```

Comment: Looks like your reducer is merely replacing a single product in your redux state. Would you not want to be storing a collection, and then pushing that object onto the array?

Comment: Hi  @user3832673, thanks for the answer. 
 AddToCart feature works, the problem is that it only doesn't update immediately. 
Do you think that it will help to update immediately?

Comment: What are you returning in your response? Is it a collection of products, or just a single one? As for updating your view, are you properly mapping state to props in your React component, i.e. whatever is calling CartItem, Profile, and all the rest? And then are you passing a reference to that redux state via props?

Comment: HI @user3832673 In response.data I am returning array of Cart "id"s:
 cart: Array(7)
0: "5f8f206c8a2b2f188cb1ff4d"
1: "5f8f206c8a2b2f188cb1ff4d"